# CSS menu triangle not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need some CSS help. There are two things I would like to achieve, but I've so far been unsuccessful.
Link to Site: http://hn.k12.oh.us/testsite/district/

When I hover over the horizontal menu (primary menu) items I want a triangle to appear. I've achieved this in the vertical menu, but cannot get it to display in the horizontal menu. I'd like it to be similar to what's going on with the vertical menu.

I'm using the following code.

```
#primary-menu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f7df2b;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

I'd like the triangle to display on the currently active menu item. I can't get this to work for either the horizontal or vertical menu.

I've tried what's above with the following css:

```
#primary-menu > ul > li.active a {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#primary-menu > ul > li:hover:after {
```

should be

```
#primary-menu ul > li:hover:after,
#primary-menu ul > li.current_page_item:after { ...
```

or

```
#primary-menu-menu > ul > li:hover:after,
#primary-menu-menu > ul > li.current_page_item:after { ...
```

You have incorrectly specified a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to figure out why your reply never showed up in my email inbox.

Comment: How do I get the triangle to appear for the active link?

Comment: The current_page_item:after working fine for the horizontal menu. The vertical menu has issues. I'm not sure I like the look of the triangle for the active menu anyway, so I think I'm going to scrap it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd like to learn what's going on with the active element. Please share if you figure it out.